# How to get a list of supported bands for a Wi-Fi network in Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming, wifi

I am a beginner in Android development and I am trying to figure out how to get a list of supported bands for a Wi-Fi network in Android. The reason I need this information is that our TVs have been performing poorly on the 2.4GHz band and we need to manually switch dual-band networks to 5GHz band.

Specifically, I need to know if a network supports 5GHz, 2.4GHz, or both at the same time. I want to be able to retrieve this information programmatically so that I can automate the process of switching to a better network for our TVs.

I have searched online for a solution, but I couldn't find any clear answers. Can anyone please help me with this? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in Android using Kotlin, you can use the WifiManager class, which provides information about the current Wi-Fi connection

```
val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
    val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
    val frequency = wifiInfo.frequency
    val is5GHz = frequency in 5_150..5_350 || frequency in 5_470..5_725 || frequency in 5_725..5_825
    val is2_4GHz = frequency in 2_400..2_483

    if (is5GHz) {
        // The network supports 5GHz band
    } else if (is2_4GHz) {
        // The network supports 2.4GHz band
    } else {
        // The network supports both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands
    }
} else {
    // Wi-Fi is not enabled
}
```

we need to check if the device is connected to a Wi-Fi network using the isWifiEnabled() method of the wifiManager object.

Comment: Are you sure this works? What if the dual band network is connected in 5GHz mode right now? We would fall into the "if (is5GHz) {}" block and the network would be considered a 5GHz band network instead of dual band, right?